# How to achieve this formatting

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form whose HTML I cannot alter.  This solution must be pure css.

I have created a jsfiddle for this issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/oewf0x04/1/

Narrow your browser with the fiddle open until the help text breaks a line, as in the image below:

[image]

Those italic help texts on "packs" and "is active" are breaking, and when they do the remainder jumps all the way down to the next available space, aka below the entire line.  How can I make it so that they align with themselves?  In other words, in the case of the "packs" text in the image, "If" should be aligned with "associated."

My first instinct was to simply give those spans `display: inline-block` - because in my mind they would then be in a block that is only as wide as the remaining space - but you can plug that into the fiddle and watch it fail.

HTML and CSS for the fiddle-averse:

```css
form p {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
}
form td {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 125px;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #DD660E;
  background-color: #fffae7;
}
form span {
  font-size: .75em;
  font-style: italic;
}
/*submit buttons*/

form > input:last-child {
  width: 100px;
}
#id_is_active {
  width: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<form action="/deck/bg-dredge/" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
    <input id="id_name" maxlength="40" name="name" type="text" value="BG Dredge">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_format">Format:</label>
    <select id="id_format" name="format">
      <option value="MODERN" selected="selected">Modern</option>
      <option value="STANDARD">Standard</option>
      <option value="LEGACY">Legacy</option>
      <option value="VINTAGE">Vintage</option>
      <option value="BLOCK">Block</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_type">Type:</label>
    <select id="id_type" name="type">
      <option value="CONSTRUCTED" selected="selected">Constructed</option>
      <option value="DRAFT">Draft</option>
      <option value="SEALED">Sealed</option>
      <option value="COMMANDER">Commander</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_packs">Packs:</label>
    <input id="id_packs" maxlength="20" name="packs" type="text" value="Unlimited"> <span class="helptext">If Block, Sealed, or Draft, note the associated packs/block</span>

  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_deck_list">Deck list:</label>
    <textarea cols="40" id="id_deck_list" name="deck_list" rows="10"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_is_active">Is active:</label>
    <input checked="checked" id="id_is_active" name="is_active" type="checkbox"> <span class="helptext">Check to hide deck from your All Active Decks view and Registration Selector.  Useful for "hiding" old or one-time limited decks.</span>

  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Update Deck">
</form>
```

Comment: The questions are different, I just didn't recognize that the method used in the first question applied to this problem as well.  Also, the answer that seemed more elegant in the first question, which I accepted, doesn't seem to be as robust as Oriol's answer.  The short answer is that I was still struggling to understand how these solutions were actually functioning.  Hopefully I'll be able to learn from these so that I can better understand the concepts and avoid having to ask a question the next time by recognizing the problem for what it is.

Comment: Also, the overflow stuff is unique to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28183241/1529630) in your other question, you can add

```css
form > p > select,
form > p > textarea,
form > p > input {
  float: left;
}
form > p > span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
form {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
form > p {
  display: table-row;
}
form > p > label {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 0;
}
form > p > input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: left;
}
form > p > select,
form > p > textarea,
form > p > input[type="text"] {
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
form > p > span {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 80%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
    <input id="id_name" maxlength="40" name="name" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_format">Format:</label>
    <select id="id_format" name="format"></select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_type">Type:</label>
    <select id="id_type" name="type"></select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_packs">Packs:</label>
    <select id="id_packs" name="packs"></select>
    <span>If Block, Sealed, or draft, note the associated packs/block</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_decklist">Decklist:</label>
    <textarea id="id_decklist" name="decklist"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_inactive">Inactive:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="id_inactive" name="inactive" />
    <span>Check to hide deck from your All Active Decks view and Registration Selector.  Useful for "hiding" old or one-time limited decks.</span>
  </p>
</form>
```

Similarly, in your current code, you can add

```css
form p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
label,
input, select, textarea {
  float: left;
}
form span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
form p {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
form td {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
}
label {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 125px;
  float: left;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #DD660E;
  background-color: #fffae7;
  float: left;
}
form span {
  font-size: .75em;
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*submit buttons*/

form > input:last-child {
  width: 100px;
}
#id_is_active {
  width: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<form action="/deck/bg-dredge/" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
    <input id="id_name" maxlength="40" name="name" type="text" value="BG Dredge">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_format">Format:</label>
    <select id="id_format" name="format">
      <option value="MODERN" selected="selected">Modern</option>
      <option value="STANDARD">Standard</option>
      <option value="LEGACY">Legacy</option>
      <option value="VINTAGE">Vintage</option>
      <option value="BLOCK">Block</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_type">Type:</label>
    <select id="id_type" name="type">
      <option value="CONSTRUCTED" selected="selected">Constructed</option>
      <option value="DRAFT">Draft</option>
      <option value="SEALED">Sealed</option>
      <option value="COMMANDER">Commander</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_packs">Packs:</label>
    <input id="id_packs" maxlength="20" name="packs" type="text" value="Unlimited"> <span class="helptext">If Block, Sealed, or Draft, note the associated packs/block</span>

  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_deck_list">Deck list:</label>
    <textarea cols="40" id="id_deck_list" name="deck_list" rows="10"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_is_active">Is active:</label>
    <input checked="checked" id="id_is_active" name="is_active" type="checkbox"> <span class="helptext">Check to hide deck from your All Active Decks view and Registration Selector.  Useful for "hiding" old or one-time limited decks.</span>

  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Update Deck">
</form>
```

The solution uses `float: left` to make the `span`s flow along the right side of the `label`s and the form controls.

This is explained in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current
>   line. The most interesting characteristic of a float (or "floated" or
>   "floating" box) is that content may flow along its side (or be
>   prohibited from doing so by the 'clear' property). Content flows down
>   the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a
>   right-floated box.

See the following schematic example:

```css
.wrapper {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border: 5px solid;
}
.float1 {
  float: left;
  height: 4em;
  background: green;
}
.float2 {
  float: left;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: red;
}
.block {
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="float1">Float 1</div>
  <div class="float2">Float 2</div>
  <div class="block">Block<br />Block</div>
</div>
```

However, this is much similar to the current situation you want to avoid!

But the trick is

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting
>   context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must
>   not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting
>   context as the element itself.

Then, using `overflow: hidden`, now we have

```css
.wrapper {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border: 5px solid;
}
.float1 {
  float: left;
  height: 4em;
  background: green;
}
.float2 {
  float: left;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: red;
}
.block {
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="float1">Float 1</div>
  <div class="float2">Float 2</div>
  <div class="block">Block<br />Block</div>
</div>
```

But wait! In case any of the floated elements is taller than the element that flows along their side, they will overflow the parent!

To avoid this, we must clear the float. One way is adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent.

Finally, we have the desired behavior:

```css
.wrapper {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid;
}
.float1 {
  float: left;
  height: 4em;
  background: green;
}
.float2 {
  float: left;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: red;
}
.block {
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="float1">Float 1</div>
  <div class="float2">Float 2</div>
  <div class="block">Block<br />Block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, it was taking me a minute to process your answer and understand it.  Indeed, it works like a charm.  Could you help me understand why the `overflow: hidden` on the `span` is necessary?  I removed it and see no change.  On a related note - why does the `overflow: hidden` on the `p` make this work?  I'm trying to understand it conceptually.

Comment: @fildred13 Yes, I will add an explanation. But `span { overflow: hidden }` matters if the text is long enough, try it.

Comment: Ah I see what happens now.  Once you explain this I'll have a long look at it to understand how this is working.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  This is an invaluable thing to understand, and now I understand it perfectly. I really appreciate it.